# How to share logic and DAL code between desktop app and WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I'm building some software that has a WPF desktop app written in C# .NET, and some locally persisted storage using a SQLite database.

I've also created a SQL Server database hosted in Azure for persisting data in the cloud, and I'm working on a ASP.NETCore Web API that will sit between the database and any clients wanting to persist data on the server.

In the process, I've realized that a bunch of code like my database connection and helpers (or at least their interfaces), and the model interfaces that define what properties a certain object (e.g. a financial transaction) can be shared and re-used across both the desktop app and the Web API.

In the future, I'm planning to have mobile apps, and they will no doubt use much of the same logic and DAL code again. So my question is: what's the best way to design the architecture so as to future-proof myself now and avoid re-factoring my code a ton of times?

My plan right now is to create an API (class library) that will contain the business logic, DAL, and data model, and for this API to be referenced by the desktop app (which then becomes just a lightweight UI layer using MVVM) and references by the Web API's controllers. I'd have one implementation inside the API designed to talk to SQLite, and another to SQL Server.

The problem/confusion I see are that I'd end up having a class library on my desktop client that persists some data locally, but it's also calling a Web API to persist data, which would then call the same class library, just stored on the server, to tell the DAL to perform some operations on the server's database.

Something seems... off, about this setup. I'm trying to simplify things and aide maintainability, but it seems like I'm over-complicating things instead. Am I missing something?

The more I read, the more it seems like there are 10 ways to do anything and it's not really clear to me what the best way is.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make both solutions communicate with a single web service for persistence?

Comment: I want to persist data locally so that users can continue using the desktop app offline, in which case the client would sync changes with the server when it can reconnect.

Comment: Ok, so do that and use the shared API when you do the sync

Comment: But the logic for persisting and querying the local database from the client is almost identical to that of Web API with respect to the server one, so I thought I should reuse that code?

Comment: This sounds like it needs a functional approach, too - if you want to store changes local to the user but validate and apply business logic later then you need to embrace asynchrony: do the most naive thing you can locally and then handle inconsistencies when the data is eventually sent to the server. When you do this, the logic for both will likely be totally different.

Comment: Don't forget that the state on the server is going to continue to change while the user works locally - any data saved locally is "dirty" until it is validated by the server anyway.

Comment: I struggle to imagine a scenario where "the logic for persisting and querying the local database from the client is almost identical to that of Web API," could possibly be true.

Comment: I hadn't considered the "dirty" aspect. I'm starting to think there won't be as much shared code as I first thought. So for instance locally the data model is going to implement INotifyPropertyChanged a lot to raise events and refresh the UI, which the Web API doesn't care about or need to do. On the other hand, most of the code for validating the data and potentially synchronizing changes from multiple clients will be in the Web API and the client doesn't care about that.

Comment: What about sharing interfaces like for my data model? So if in the future I add a column to a table, I do it in a shared interface and all the code that references it has to implement the change.